# Параметры обычной LSTM

Tags: нейронные-сети

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- xt — входной вектор,
- ht — выходной вектор,
- ct — вектор состояний,
- W, U и b — матрицы параметров и вектор,
- ft, it и ot — векторы вентилей,

  - ft — вектор вентиля забывания, вес запоминания старой информации,
  - it — вектор входного вентиля, вес получения новой информации,
  - ot — вектор выходного вентиля, кандидат на выход.

> Собственно сам вопрос, xt, ht это понятно - xt массив [0.5, 0.2, 0.3]
>   t=1..3 (три замера разных параметров, допустим температуры, влажности,
>   давления), а ht является результатом вычисления [..., ... , ...] ;
>
> Если верить wiki, c и h это тоже массивы размером 3, у которых первый
>   элемент равен 0, а остальные вычисляются далее.
>
> Wfio и Ufio - это веса в LSTM-блоке, но я не могу понять какая
>   структура весов (подозреваю что шесть массивов (Wf, Wi, Wo ...)
>   размера 3, на один t, то-есть на все 3t нам потребуется 6*3=18
>   массивов размера 3 (кол-во вх. параметров)) и чем инциализируется эта
>   структура (думаю random'ными числами)?
>
> Вот самое что не понятное и хотел я у вас спросить, что такое b, ft,it
>   и ot, а точнее какова структура и чем инциализируется?

Comment: да уж... RNN и LSTM в частности - очень непросто понять... У меня пока только поверхностное понимание того как это работает... Ответы на некоторые из ваших вопросов: `b*` - это `bias` вектора для различных параметров. `ft` - `forget gate's activation vector`, `it` - `input gate's activation vector`, `ot` - `output gate's activation vector` - они используются для вычисления вектора состояний (`memory cells` - "запоминающих" ячеек). Инициализируются все веса и смещения (bias) случайными значениями с нормальным распределением.